# Medidas estándar para las media queries

Tags: css, html5, web, responsive

Estoy haciendo una app web que tiene que ser accesible desde pc, tablet y ordenador de escritorio. Sé como funcionan las media queries, que dependiendo de la cantidad de píxeles que ponga, lee el css que tiene entre las llaves.

Ejemplo:

```
/*Tablet*/
/*portrait*/
@media screen and (max-width:768px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    body{background: yellow;}
}

/*landscape*/
@media screen and (max-width:768px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    body{background: green;}
}
/*fin tablet*/
```

El problema está en qué medidas poner en min-width y max-width. Tengo problemas sobre todo con los dispositivos móbiles, y me gustaría saber si hay un estándar que diga:

- de x pixeles a x pixeles móviles, de y a y píxeles tablets y de z a z píxeles pantallas de escritorio y laptops

En caso de que no haya un estándar predeterminado, agradecería si compartieseis vuestro método para hacer una web responsive o mobile first.

Gracias.

/*Añadido después de haber sido resuelta la duda*/

He puesto en mi código las siguientes media queries y funcionan, por si alguien se pasa por aquí y quiere un copiapega fácil:

```
/*Escritorio*/
@media (min-width: 1199.98px)  {
    body{background: red;}
}
/*Fin Escritorio*/

/*Tablet*/
/*Portrait*/
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 991.98px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    body{background: orange;}
}

/*landscape*/
@media (min0-width: 991.98px) and (max-width: 1199.98px)and (orientation:landscape) {
    body{background: blue;}
}
/*fin tablet*/

/*movil*/
/*Portrait*/
/*Default*/
@media (max-width: 575.98px)and (orientation:portrait) {
    body{background: green;}
 }
/*landscape*/
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 991.98px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    body{background: black;}
}
/*fin movil*/
```

Comment: Yo suelo basarme en los tamaños que define Bootstrap, cuyo uso está bastante extendido. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, llevaba un tiempo haciéndolo con medidas al azar jeje, si quieres escribe tu respuesta en el apartado de respuestas y la marco como correcta. Un saludo @phpMyGuel

Comment: Sin fallo. Un placer ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las medidas depende mucho del fabricante, dispositivo y orientación, sin contar que también debes pensar que no siempre las medidas serán exactas para todos los dispositivos, pero aún así existe un estándar con el que te puedes guiar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mediante esta imagén te puedes guiar mas fácilmente.

De igual forma te dejo unos [enlace1](https://www.destacaimagen.com/diseno-y-maquetacion-web-smartphones-y-tablets/), [enlace2](https://uniwebsidad.com/foro/pregunta/184/medidas-recomendadas-para-los-media-queries-de-css/) donde puedes encontrar más al respecto.

Mucha suerte.

Answer (score -2):

Te recomiendo que no sigas ningún estandar y que utilices tus media-queries dependiendo de tus necesidades.

En las dev tools de Chrome tienes una fantástica herramienta para comprobar los puntos de ruptura que te hacen falta dependiendo del tamaño del viewport que tengas en ese momento.

Si además trabajas las media-queries con algún preprocesador tipos Sass, less o stylus, te será mucho más cómodo y rápido trabajar el responsive de tu proyecto.

Comment: Mis necesidades son que cualquier dispositivo que quiera acceder  a mi web pueda hacerlo sin que explote el contenido de la web. Creo que las medidas que me han pasado son muy últiles ya que he probado a acceder desde Escritorio, tablet y móvil y funciona correctamente.Nunca he usado ningún preprocesador, los estilos siempre los he hecho directamente en el css.

Comment: Razón de más para no ceñirte a 4 breakpoints. Si accedo a tu aplicación web desde mi televisor de 50 pulgadas, tu web estará adaptada? O si abro tu web desde mi mac con la ventana del navegador resizeada a como la tenía de la web anterior (por ejemplo con un ancho de 712px) también tendrás todos los elementos adaptados? La metodología responsive no es que se vea bien en un iPad, un iPhone y cuatro versiones de Samsung si no que la web nunca se rompa en ninguna resolución. En cuanto a los preprocesadores, te ánimo a que empieces a trabajar con uno :)